# How to make tsyringe (dep injection lib) resolve classes that have dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dependency-injection, tsyringe

I am clearly misunderstanding how TSyringe is supposed to resolve classes with dependencies.

I created a minimal repro. In my index.tsx, I do as they indicate in the docs and import `reflect-metadata`. This example works if I inject a `singleton` class with no dependencies:

```
// index.tsx
import "reflect-metadata";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />,  document.getElementById('root'));
```

A single singleton class:

```
// _A.ts
import {inject, singleton} from 'tsyringe';

@singleton()
export class A {    
    get_msg() {
        return "Worked!";
    }
}
```

And the component that uses it:

```
// App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {container} from "tsyringe";
import {A} from "./_A";

interface Props {
  a?: A
}

function App({a = container.resolve(A)}: Props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          {a.get_msg()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run the app, the Worked! text is printed as expected.

However, if I create a second singleton called B:

```
// _B.ts
import {singleton} from 'tsyringe';

@singleton()
export class B {
    get_msg() {
        return "Worked!";
    }
}
```

And then inject `B` into `A` to get the message:

```
// _A.ts
import {inject, singleton} from 'tsyringe';
import {B} from "./_B";

@singleton()
export class _A {
    constructor(private b: B) {
    }

    get_msg() {
        return this.b.get_msg();
    }
}
```

Then it fails with `Uncaught Error: TypeInfo not known for "A"`

I have:

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

on my `tsconfig.ts`, as they indicate in the README.

Shouldn't Syringe resolve B automatically, inject B into A and then inject A into my app component so I can print the message?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I figured this out.

To keep the typescript metadata and allow reflect-metadata to do its thing, we need to add `babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata` to the project.

However, in order to customize create-react-app, you need the `craco` library. There are several out there, but craco is the only one I could that supports CRA 4.x. **You cannot be on the latest (CRA 5.0) as none of these libs support it yet.**

So:

1 - Install Craco and set it up.

2 - Install `babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata` as a dev dependency

3 - Add a `craco.config.js` file to your project to load this plugin:

```
module.exports = function ({ env: _env }) {
    return {
        babel: {
            plugins: [
                "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata"
            ]
        },
    };
};
```

4 - Make sure to update your package.json to launch with craco so that the config override takes place:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
```

That's it, it will work now. Hope it helps someone out there.